# VB6 Error: Runtime error 3021. Either BOF or EOF is true or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record

Tags: vb6

This is my code:

```
Dim c As Integer
Private Sub Command4_Click()
c = InputBox("ENTER STAFF ID")
Form6.Adodc1.Refresh
Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst `ERROR
While Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.EOF <> True
If Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(0) = Val(c) Then
Text1.Text = Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(0)
Text1.Enabled = False
Text2.Text = Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(1)
Text3.Text = Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(2)
Text4.Text = Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.Fields(5)
DTPicker2.Enabled = False
DTPicker1.Enabled = False
MsgBox "AFTER EDITING CLICK ON UPDATE"
Command2.Enabled = True
Exit Sub
Else
Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext
End If
Wend
MsgBox "ENTER CORRECT STAFF ID"
End Sub
```

This is the error I have received during runtime:

```
VB6 Error: Runtime error 3021. Either BOF or EOF is true or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.
```

I have already the other questions, I haven't got an answer in those solved ones as this is in VB6. I have also mentioned in which do i get the error when I click on debug. TIA

Comment: BOF or EOF is true if the source for your `Adodc1.Recordset` has no records.  It would be a bit easier to help if you provided ALL the necessary info to debug the issue.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru : Hi, I am new to Stackoverflow. May i please know what details are you looking for? So i can step forward and share.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown the source for your recordsource. Have you done any debugging at all to confirm that you get any records?

Answer (score 2):

The new recordset will already be on the first record if any are returned.  You do not need

```
Form6.Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst `ERROR
```

Indeed it is causing an error probably because there are no records returned, and thus no first record to move to.  If you check BOF at that line, you'll find that both BOF and EOF are true.